# Picking A Video File From PhotoLibrary With SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am using following code to get video's URL which are in photo library.

It presents list of video files in photo library and you choose one of them.

It then opens an other view with cancel, play and choose buttons at bottom.

You have to touch choose button here again to get URL of the video file.

I want to get URL at first step but how.

```
struct VideoPickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

var videoURL: URL?

@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    var parent: VideoPickerView

    init(parent: VideoPickerView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    
    
    
    func imagePickerController (
        _ picker: UIImagePickerController,
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]
    ) {
        
        
        
        if let mediaType = info[.mediaType] as? String,
              mediaType == UTType.movie.identifier,
              let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] as? URL ?? info[.mediaURL] as? URL {

              // Handle the video URL
              print("url \(videoURL)")

              @ObservedObject var fileInfo = SharedFileInfo.shared
              parent.videoURL = videoURL
              fileInfo.videoURL = videoURL
              fileInfo.menuIndex = 34
          }

        parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }

    // top blue cancel
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        @ObservedObject var fileInfo = SharedFileInfo.shared
       
        fileInfo.menuIndex = 0
        parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        
    }
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(parent: self)
}

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = context.coordinator
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.mediaTypes = [UTType.movie.identifier]
    picker.allowsEditing = false


    return picker
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}

}
```

Comment: You could try declaring `@StateObject var fileInfo = SharedFileInfo.shared`
  just once, e.g just before `var videoURL: URL?`, and use that `fileInfo` in your code.
 
 Note, the singleton pattern is not required if you pass the model to other views using the more common
 `.environmentObject()`